# Always Have Text in the Middle of the Page

Tags: html, css

I basically want to have my text in the middle of the page and the font size relative to the screen that it will be on.

I am basically trying to put together an app that will display tweets to the browser, it is pretty simple.

So far I have the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

  <link rel=StyleSheet href="/static/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
  {{ tweet }}
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And I am using padding to get the text in the middle:

```
html, body {
  background-color: #c13192;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;

}
```

I'd like the ccontent to be in the middle of the screen always without any need for the page to expand past the screen. Therefore no need for scrolling and the content will always be sized appropriately to be in the middle.

EDIT: I think I have managed to solved it with a simple overflow: hidden;

Comment: Handle div centering position using margin:0 auto; and adjust fonts using media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center something in the center/middle of the page, you can use a combination of `left: 50%; top: 50%;` with `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` which will center it both horizontally and vertically.

To adapt the font size to be relative to the screen it's on, you can use `vw` and `vh` units.

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  font-size: calc(1em + 1vw);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  <link rel=StyleSheet href="/static/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
  {{ tweet }}
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use paddings to center a div or element in general.
You can use `text-align:center;` to center a lot of things. On Divs, you need to do `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` to center them in parent.

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #c13192;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 20%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  <link rel=StyleSheet href="/static/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

</head>

<body>

<div class="content">
  I am the tweet content
</div>


</body>
</html>
```